# How to join a column of lists in one dataframe with a column of strings in another dataframe?

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, join, inner-join

I have two dataframes. The first one (let's call it A) has a column (let's call it 'col1') whose elements are lists of strings. The other one (let's call it B) has a column (let's call it 'col2') whose elements are strings. I want to do a join between these two dataframes where B.col2 is in the list in A.col1. This is one-to-many join.

Also, I need the solution to be scalable since I wanna join two dataframes with hundreds of thousands of rows.

I have tried concatenating the values in A.col1 and creating a new column (let's call it 'col3') and joining with this condition: A.col3.contains(B.col2). However, my understanding is that this condition triggers a cartesian product between the two dataframes which I cannot afford considering the size of the dataframes.

```
def joinIds(IdList):
  return "__".join(IdList)
joinIds_udf = udf(joinIds)

pnr_corr = pnr_corr.withColumn('joinedIds', joinIds_udf(pnr_corr.pnrCorrelations.correlationPnrSchedule.scheduleIds)

pnr_corr_skd = pnr_corr.join(skd, pnr_corr.joinedIds.contains(skd.id), how='inner')
```

This is a sample of the join that I have in mind:

```
dataframe A:
listColumn
["a","b","c"]
["a","b"]
["d","e"]

dataframe B:
valueColumn
a
b
d

output:
listColumn      valueColumn
["a","b","c"]   a
["a","b","c"]   b
["a","b"]       a
["a","b"]       b
["d","e"]       d
```

Comment: Can you give a small example with the expected output?

Comment: @Nakor please check out these links. Thanks A: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydPsK.png
B: https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1Z8N.png
final result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2cW3.png

Comment: You should edit your post and add these. Also, it's always much easier if you put in plain text format (makes it easier to test solutions). Another thing is that your example doesnt show what happens when an element in B is in several entries of A. What do you do in these cases?

Comment: I couldn't add picture apparently I need 10 reputations first. I added the text format. about your question, in that case we'll have multiple rows in the output. I'll add it to the example in the main question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there is an efficient way to do it, but this gives the correct output:

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import chain

df1 = pd.Series([["a","b","c"],["a","b"],["d","e"]])
df2 = pd.Series(["a","b","d"])

result = [ [ [el2,list1] for el2 in df2.values if el2 in list1 ] 
                         for list1 in df1.values ]
result_flat = list(chain(*result))

result_df = pd.DataFrame(result_flat)
```

You get:

```
In [26]: result_df
Out[26]:
   0          1
0  a  [a, b, c]
1  b  [a, b, c]
2  a     [a, b]
3  b     [a, b]
4  d     [d, e]
```

Another approach is to use the new `explode()` method from **pandas>=0.25** and merge like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [["a","b","c"],["a","b"],["d","e"]]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col2': ["a","b","d"]})

df1_flat = df1.col1.explode().reset_index()
df_merged = pd.merge(df1_flat,df2,left_on='col1',right_on='col2')

df_merged['col2'] = df1.loc[df_merged['index']].values
df_merged.drop('index',axis=1, inplace=True)
```

This gives the same result:

```
  col1       col2
0    a  [a, b, c]
1    a     [a, b]
2    b  [a, b, c]
3    b     [a, b]
4    d     [d, e]
```

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately I can’t use for loops since I want to use the code to join two dataframes with hundreds of thousands of rows.

Comment: Check out the second approach I added, maybe it's better

Answer (score -1):

How about:

```
df['col1'] = [df['col1'].values[i] + [df['col2'].values[i]] for i in range(len(df))]
```

Where 'col1' is the list of strings and 'col2' is the strings.

You can also drop 'col2' if you don't want it anymore with:

```
df = df.drop('col2',axis=1)
```

Comment: There are two dataframes and I'm trying to join them. Ur answer has both of the columns in one dataframe